# Unity multiple GUITextures placing together breaking up in different device modes

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Hi I am a newbie in Unity 3d. While cooking up with 2D gaming in Unity 4.3,  am not sure how to place a navigation control.

Here I have tried putting together few GUITextures, one beside another & control the player navigations- which is working pretty well.

But, if I change the game window view-modes to different devices, its breaking apart.

Please suggest what should be the approach- to apply such a game control.

These are the screenshots for- Free Aspect & a iPhone wide mode views

[image]

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is the screenshot of the editor-
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing you are hard coding your positions? Try using the screen.width and screen.height variables to position your gui... You can also scale them using that too...

Comment: I have hard coded in the Unity Editor. Let me add a screenshot